# Algebraic simplification including square roots $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt{2}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

This may be stupid, but how do I see that $$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt{2}} - 1 = 1 + \sqrt{2}$$
having only the left-hand side?

Comment: Do you mean doing something like $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt{2}} - 1 =\ldots = 1 + \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to write $2(3+2\sqrt 2)=6+4\sqrt 2$ as a square of $a+b\sqrt 2$ for some rational numbers $a,b$:
$$(a+b\sqrt 2)^2=a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt2 \;=\; 6+4\sqrt 2$$
By $\Bbb Q$-linear independence of $1$ and $\sqrt 2$, this implies $$ab=2,a^2+2b^2=6$$
Can you take it from here?

---

Here are some hints, if needed:

> If we try to find integer solutions $a,b$, we easily find $a=2,b=1$ as solution.
>  Therefore:
> $$\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt{3+2\sqrt 2}= \sqrt{6+4\sqrt 2} = \sqrt{(2+\sqrt 2)^2}=2+\sqrt 2$$

Comment: You can also "see" : $6+4\sqrt 2 = 4+2\cdot 2 \sqrt 2 + 2 = (2+\sqrt 2)^2$

Answer (score 3):

You may note that $3+2\sqrt{2}=(1+\sqrt{2})^2$. Hence, we have
$$
\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}-1=\sqrt{2}(1+\sqrt{2})-1=\sqrt{2}+2-1=\sqrt{2}+1,
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

To denest the nested radical $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}$, we have a useful formula. Namely

> Given a radical of the form $\sqrt{X\pm Y}$, we can rewrite it into$$\sqrt{X\pm Y}=\sqrt{\frac {X+\sqrt{X^2-Y^2}}2}\pm\sqrt{\frac {X-\sqrt{X^2-Y^2}}{2}}\tag1$$
>   With $X>Y$ and $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}$.

In $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}$, we have $X=3,Y=\sqrt8$. Using $(1)$, we get$$\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}=\left(\frac {3+1}2\right)^{1/2}+\left(\frac {3-1}2\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt2+1\tag2$$

From here, can you continue?